# I want to export an Postgres Table as an CSV File as a download button on Flask. How to do that?

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask

I have a table on my PSQL and I want to export it as a downloadable file to any user who clicks on the download button and hence my path is not fixed. The copy command doesn't work for me here. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@app.route("/")
@roles_required('member')
def index():
    return render_template("pages/index.html")

@app.route("/download_csv")
@roles_required('member')
def download_csv():
    conn = None
    cursor = None

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=db user=u password=p")

        cursor = conn.cursor()
  
        cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM table')
        # conn.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchall()  # fetchone()

        output = io.StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(output)

        line = ['column1,column2']
        writer.writerow(line)

        for row in result:
            line = [row[0] + ' , ' + row[1] + ' , ']
            writer.writerow(line)

        output.seek(0)

        return Response(output, mimetype="text/csv",
                        headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=report.csv"})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

index.html

```
...

    <a href="{{ url_for('app.download_csv') }}" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        Download Csv  <i class="fa fa-file-csv"></i>
                    </a>

...
```